# Not Able to receive data from api server( with public ip) using ngReouce

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this question in naive, but i stuck and new to angular. I search enough but not able to comeup with solution.

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngResource']);
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$resource',function ($scope,$resource) {
// body...
var data= $resource('http://ip/category/something',{"p1":76,"p3":9}, { charge: { method: 'POST' } });
console.log(data);
```

}]);

I am not able to fetch the data from the server and it return a function.
I need explanation if it is possible.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/  take a look at this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have is that the `$resource` service isnt a function that returns data from a request, it returns a `$resource` object, that has predefined methods to make those requests.

heres how you should do it to get what your looking for

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngResource']);
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$resource','$q',function($scope,$resource,$q) {
    // body...
    var data,
        dataResource = $resource('http://ip/category/something',{"p1":76,"p3":9}, { charge: { method: 'POST' } });
    data = dataResource.get();
    $q.when(data.$promise).then(function(){
        console.log(data);
    });
}])
```

```

or something like that.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load /api/v1/?p1=76&p3=9. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access...

But i am able to access it using POSTMAN

Comment: there are certain headers that need to be set on the servers response, for requests from javascript code to work, mainly: